# Django TestCase object has no attribute 'login'

Tags: django, django-testing

I have used selenium to test my login method and it works fine.  Then, I tried to test other parts of the website.  So, I needed to create a user in my test.  To do that, I've used client instead of request factory (since there are middleware classes).  However, I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ProjectListTestCase' object has no attribute 'login'
```

I do have a custom authentication backend to allow for email address to be used instead of username:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'phonenumber_field',
'rest_framework',

# 3rd party apps
'crispy_forms',

# Local apps 
'accounts',
...
```

I tried the code in the console:

```
>>> the_client = Client()
>>> the_client.login(email='test@testing.com', password='testingPassword')
True
```

Here is the code in my test_views.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import RequestFactory

from model_mommy import mommy
from selenium import webdriver

from project_profile.models import Project
from user_profile.models import UserProfile

class ProjectListTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        # login the user
        self.login = self.client.login(email='test@testing.com', password='testingPassword')
        print ('Login successful? ', self.login)          # Just to see what's going on

        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('development:list_view_developmentproject') )
        print('response: ', self.response)                # Just to see what's going on


    def test_user_login(self):           
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)
```

Why do I get the error when running the test, but using the same code in the console runs fine?

**Edit 1:** Changed the login and response in setUp to self.login and self.response to preserve consistency. I still get an error:

```
TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

**Edit 2:** Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\firone\development\tests\test_views.py", line 25, in setUp
    self.response = self.client.get(reverse('development:list_view_developmentproject'))
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 536, in get
    **extra)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 340, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 416, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 501, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 160, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\firone\development\views\views_main.py", line 2057, in get_queryset
    user_development_projects = Project.objects.filter(project__users = logged_in_user)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1276, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1179, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(field, value, opts)
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1078, in check_related_objects
    for v in value:
  File "C:\Users\EarlyCoder\Environments\firone_3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 239, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.563s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Edit 3:** Adding `DevelopmentProjectList`

```
class DevelopmentProjectList(ListView):
    model = DevelopmentProject
    template_name = 'development/development.html'
    context_object_name = 'development_projects'



    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logged_in_user = self.request.user
        user_development_projects = DevelopmentProject.objects.filter(project__users = logged_in_user)

        return user_development_projects
```

Comment: `print ('Login successful? ', self.login)` you have not assigned login to `self` it is just a local variable. You either need to assign it to `self` (`self.login = self.client.login(...)` or reference it not as an attribute on `self'` (`print ('Login successful? '. login)`)

Comment: Same for `self.response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259035/django-testcase-object-has-no-attribute-login#comment104727348_59259035), you haven't ***assigned*** the variable **`login`** to **`self`**
You should do something like this,

```
class ProjectListTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # login the user
        self.login = self.client.login(email='test@testing.com', password='testingPassword')
        print('Login successful? ', self.login)  # Just to see what's going on

        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('development:list_view_developmentproject'))
        print('response: ', self.response)  # Just to see what's going on

    def test_user_login(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)
```

---

### Update-1

In your view, you are not enforcing the user to be logged-in. So, add [**`LoginRequiredMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) mixin class to your view as below

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class DevelopmentProjectList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    ...
    # your code
```

Comment: Although **login** should be changed to **self.login**, it has no effect on the actual login process.  Login `self.client.login` should return **True** or **False** regardless of where you put it, **login** or **self.login**.  From then on, **self.client** should be authenticated to return a response with the **status_code** of 200. I did change my code to what you suggested, but I still get an error:  `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

Comment: It has no effect on the login process, but it has an effect on the error you've mentioned in your original post.

Comment: @EarlyCoder, either way, you should add your complete error traceback

Comment: You are correct in noticing one error, `AttributeError: 'ProjectListTestCase' object has no attribute 'login'`  However, the main error is due to login: `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable` I will upvote your answer as it did successfully debug one error, but I will still wait for the answer that resolves the main error.

Comment: it doesn't matter you upvote or not, We need more clarity on your issue, for that you should add your error traceback.

Comment: I just did.  Hope that clarifies it a bit

Comment: Yeah...that's great. Can you add your `development:list_view_developmentproject` view function/class?

Comment: See edit 3 for the view corresponding to development:list_view_developmentproject

Comment: Looks like you are on to something here.  The error has changed to `self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200) AssertionError: 302 != 200`

Comment: It's not an error...its from your test. The response indicate that, view returned 302 status

Comment: Yes, I realize that. So, does that mean that ALL my views have to use the mixin? This does sound a bit too much given that they work fine without the mixin

Comment: If you want to enforce the login process, you should be

Comment: So, it turns out that I missed to include a decorated dispatch method. So, the alternative to using the mixin is to use `@method_decorator(login_required)` on dispatch.  This was hard to debug as my same code worked on some other project, and I was not able to find out what gave rise to the error. Thank you so much for taking the time and getting to the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

**Either use `login`/`response` or `self.login`/`self.response` in consistently** - based on whether you want to use it in `test_user_login`

You're assigning the variable `login` here:

```
login = self.client.login(email='test@testing.com', password='testingPassword')
```

Then attempting to access `self.login` here:

```
print ('Login successful? ', self.login)          # Just to see what's going on
```

Same applies for `response` and `self.response`

Final code can look something like:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import RequestFactory

from model_mommy import mommy
from selenium import webdriver

from project_profile.models import Project
from user_profile.models import UserProfile

class ProjectListTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        # login the user
        self.login = self.client.login(email='test@testing.com', password='testingPassword')
        print ('Login successful? ', self.login)          # Just to see what's going on

        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('development:list_view_developmentproject') )
        print('response: ', self.response)                # Just to see what's going on


    def test_user_login(self):           
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Although login should be changed to self.login, it has no effect on the actual login process.  Login `self.client.login` should return **True** or **False** regardless of where you put it, **login** or **self.login**.  From then on, **self.client** should be authenticated to return a response with the **status_code** of 200. I did change my code to what you suggested, but I still get an error:  `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`